# edit api method error edit api code dose not working?

Tags: asp.net, api, .net-core, edit

Error in putempdetail edit api not working

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("PutEmpDetail")]
public async Task<ActionResult<EmpDetail>> PutEmpDetail(int id,EmpDetail empDetail)

{
    var obj = _empcontext.EmpDetails.Where(x => x.Id == empDetail.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (obj != null)
    {
        obj.empcode = empDetail.empcode;
        obj.empname = empDetail.empname;
        obj.salary = empDetail.salary;
        await _empcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return CreatedAtAction("GetempDetail", empDetail);
    }
}
```

error in putempdetail edit api not working

[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: empDetail.Id null

Comment: error in a PutEmpDetail please show i was upload a image

Answer (score 1):

you must do a return for all action paths

```
 if (obj != null)
{
    obj.empcode = empDetail.empcode;
    obj.empname = empDetail.empname;
    obj.salary = empDetail.salary;
    await _empcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return CreatedAtAction("GetempDetail", empDetail);
}else{
    return BadRequest();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the case where the **obj** is null.

You can catch exception or return a badRequest.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide some code to exemplify your solution.